# twitter-bootstrap tabs with secondary navigation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I don't know if this is possible but wanted to check. I have 3 tabs set up with additional forward and backward links on each tab content pane. I need the forward and backward links to also bind with the main tab navigation. Right now they don't trigger the active state on the main nav tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you linked your forward and backward links on the `.tab-content` where you should have bound the tabs `.nav-tabs a`.

That way you can trigger the `$nextTab.tab('show')` which would take care of the tab navigation and the tab content.

Check this example to to better understand my point : http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/3hsBB/